# Site-wide reusable ngx-datatable footer template

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable, ng-template

When creating custom footer templates for ngx-datatable (https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) I don't want to have to duplicate the footer template in every page that uses the datatable.

What would be the angular2 way to create a reusable template that I could use in all of my datatables?

```
<ngx-datatable-footer>
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template let-rowCount="rowCount" let-pageSize="pageSize" let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
               let-curPage="curPage" let-offset="offset" let-isVisible="isVisible">
    <div>
      Displaying {{((offset * pageSize) + 1).toLocaleString()}}-{{lastItemOffset().toLocaleString()}}
            of {{rowCount.toLocaleString()}} entries
    </div>
    <datatable-pager [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-left'" [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-right'" [pagerPreviousIcon]="'datatable-icon-prev'"
                           [pagerNextIcon]="'datatable-icon-skip'" [page]="curPage" [size]="pageSize" [count]="rowCount" [hidden]="false"
                           (change)="table.onFooterPage($event)">
    </datatable-pager>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-footer>
```

Comment: you could create a component and make use of [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to trigger actions on parent components as well as [Input and Output](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) variables to pass data to it

Comment: That is the approach I was using but it seems very verbose since you had to add all variables to the template and then to the component that the template wraps

Comment: Could you please explain where the values are coming from for the ng-template? For example let-rowCount="rowCount". I've seen several examples they all have these same attributes and settings but I cannot find anything that tells me where the value of "rowCount" comes from or is being set on.